# Who was following the "liars" in Pretty Little Liars Season 2 Episode 13?

Tags: pretty-little-liars

The same person following Alison m the store and the same person attacking her in the haunted house probably. But who can it be? Is it Mona? But she's dressed as Catwoman. I'm perplexed and can't find out who the stalker person really is... Thanks!

Comment: i watched all seasons but still its a perplexing show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know & it hasn't been answered.**

Firstly its not Mona, **it was a guy who attacked Ali**. It was supposed to be Noel BUT

> Noel then approaches Ali to apologize, but she tells him it was
>   perfect—but then realizes he's apologizing because he didn't make it
>   to the plot; he was stuck at the party, not because he had been too
>   rough with her.

In the next scene they then show

> Suddenly, a guy in an identical costume, brushes past Alison and
>   mutters "bitch." Alison looks offended, and the guy takes off his mask
>   as he walks away, revealing that he is Lucas.

BUT THEN,

> The scene then reveals several other people wearing identical masks
>   and burlap costumes. Someone a few paces away suspense fully takes off
>   his/her mask, **but the face is not shown**.

So we can rule out:
Noel, Lucas

It could be:
Ian or any other guy Ali knew back then but also worked with the then "A".

This isn't answered in any subsequent episodes if i'm not wrong (correct me if i am) & we can only guess, never know, the show has so many loop holes, its dizzy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got some spoilers and I know some stuff about A so I thought of Mona for now but I'm not certain how she could have been in all these places, or fake look like a man? I'm so perplexed, I fear the creator didn't think about all the A-like scenes carefully and just did it for the scare factor. But thanks for the detailed reply!

Comment: Though its a good show.. most of the times PLL has lot of plot-holes and questions they didnt answer !! they did a lot of scenes which make no sense whatsoever everytime A, UberA, AD is revealed

Comment: Do you happen to know of a YouTube video (or series) or an article that explains this stuff other than the wiki?

Comment: @Zap i dont have one specific on hand but there are a lot of blogs that talk about the plotholes on Pretty Little Liars that you could look at.. your question and any other questions that you have may be covered.. BUT if youre watching it for the first time and youre still in season 2, stay away from the blogs. I will try to put up a link meanwhile which doesnt spoil it for you